# How to save NSArray data in coredata?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray

I want to save my data in coredata from `NSArray`. How can I achieve this ?

```
NSArray *fetchdata = [Lockbox arrayForKey:@"fetch"];
```

Here, I am getting data in below form:

[image]

How can I save this data in `NSManageobject`?

Here is my try:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchrequestforside=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"demo"];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newDevice1 = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"demo"
             inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSArray *fetchdata = [Lockbox arrayForKey:@"fetch"]; // 

for (int i =0;i<[fetchdata count];i++){
    NSString *Name = [[fetchdata objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *Websitename = [[fetchdata objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"websitename"];
    NSString *Feedlink = [[fetchdata objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"feedurl"];

    NSLog(@"value:%@,%@,%@",Name,Websitename,Feedlink);
    [newDevice1 setValue:Name  forKey:@"name"];

    [newDevice1 setValue:Websitename  forKey:@"websitename"];
    [newDevice1 setValue:Feedlink forKey:@"feedurl"];
    NSLog(@"value:%@,%@,%@",Name,Websitename,Feedlink);

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

But with this technique I am getting an error. How can I resolve this problem?

EDIT:-

I am getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff262520660'

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: @johnykumar i am getting this error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff262520660'

Comment: check that you have created demo table in coredata file and demo table is having three columns websitename,feedurl,name.

Comment: yes . i have checked it . demotable is available with 3 column and same name .

Comment: what is lockboxfetch i think you should have fetchdata instead of lockboxfetch in for loop for (int i =0;i<[fetchdata count];i++){

Comment: What is `Lockbox` and what class is `lockboxfetch` and is it a typo from `fetchdata`?

Comment: @johnykumar :"- sorry it's a typo. please check. it's array in which i am getting my data

Comment: @Wain :- yes. it is a typo. sorry for that. corrected it. and Lockbox is a library which stores data in keychain.. https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox

Comment: have you tried deleting application and run again or with debug?

Comment: @johnykumar yes i tried it several times. I think there are some mistake in for loop .

Comment: so it is crashing at this line NSString *Name  =[[fetchdata objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];.

Comment: put breakpoint on this line and in console write this :   po fetchdata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93789/discussion-between-krina-patel-and-johny-kumar).

Comment: @krina_patel - First, **please** format any code samples so that they look nice and are easy to read on SO.  Yes, it takes a bit more time, but it's **much** easier to read.  Also, please post the implementation for `+[Lockbox arrayForKey]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code treats the contents of the `fetchdata` array as instances of `NSDictionary`, but, `LockBox` only appears to support string contents:

```
-(NSArray *)arrayForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSArray *array = nil;
    NSString *components = [self objectForKey:key];
    if (components)
        array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[components componentsSeparatedByString:kDelimiter]];

    return array;
}
```

So, you need to deal with the conversion. You're probably part dealing with it already to store the original array...

But, that's why you get the error, the code expects a dictionary but actually gets a string

Comment: :- thanks for the replay. can you explain bitmore. i can't understand exactly. and I think lockbox supports array and dictionaries.

Comment: which part? start by logging `fetchdata` and explaining how you set data in `LockBox` in the first place

Comment: I think lockbox supports array and dictionary . i have stored data in lockbox array.

Comment: the interface does, but the implementation only seems to deal with arrays of strings

Comment: so , what i have to do in this case ? means how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Show what you have and how you set it into lockbox. i don't know how to fix it because i don't know whats in it...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an object that looks like this?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface demo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * websitename;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * feedurl;

@end
```

After creating an object like this (using insertNewObjectForEntityForName) try to fetch it like that:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Btw, I would recommended you to stick to the naming conventions and call it Demo. 
Cheers

Comment: all are string. and after setting this object how can i fetch it ?

Comment: Sorry, I've changed everything to NSString. 
The insertNewObjectForEntityForName has to fetch the object with the name who matches the NSMangedObject name (in your case: demo)

I fetch my entities like that: 
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: The comment is a bit messy - I will just add it to the answer

Answer (score -2):

I advice you to use the awesome library MagicalRecord 
it save much time and very easy 
here its tutorial
[MagicalRecord Tutorial](http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/)